# Why does Fourier give a large error in MachinePrecision?

Tags: fourier-analysis, arbitrary-precision

Consider this code:

```
f[x_] = Cos[2 π x];

N0 = 10;

ls = Most @ Array[f, N0, {0, 1}]
(* 
  {1, Cos[(2 π)/9], Sin[π/18], -(1/2), -Cos[π/9], -Cos[π/9], 
  -(1/2), Sin[π/18], Cos[(2 π)/9]}
*)
```

Since the function is a periodic function, I would expect the Fourier transform give only two non-zero coefficients. Using `Fourier` I get

```
Fourier[ls]
(* 
  {-6.4763*10^-17 + 0. I, 1.5 + 5.55112*10^-17 I, 1.60247*10^-17 + 2.77556*10^-17 I, 
   3.23815*10^-17 - 8.01234*10^-18 I, -1.60247*10^-17 - 2.77556*10^-17 I, 
   -1.60247*10^-17 + 2.77556*10^-17 I, 3.23815*10^-17 + 8.01234*10^-18 I, 
   1.60247*10^-17 - 2.77556*10^-17 I, 1.5 - 5.55112*10^-17 I}
*)
```

there is an error about 10^-17.

However, if I change the precision, I get

```
Fourier[SetPrecision[ls, 8]]
(* 
  {0.*10^-8, 1.5000000 + 0.*10^-8 I, 0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I, 0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I, 
   0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I, 0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I, 0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I, 
   0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I, 1.5000000 + 0.*10^-8 I}
*)

Fourier[SetPrecision[ls, 16]]
(* 
  {0.*10^-16, 1.500000000000000 + 0.*10^-16 I, 0.*10^-16 + 0.*10^-16 I, 
   0.*10^-16 + 0.*10^-16 I, 0.*10^-16 + 0.*10^-16 I, 0.*10^-16 + 0.*10^-16 I, 
   0.*10^-16 + 0.*10^-16 I, 0.*10^-16 + 0.*10^-16 I, 1.500000000000000 + 0.*10^-16 I}
*)

Fourier[SetPrecision[ls, 32]]
(* 
  {0.*10^-32, 1.5000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.*10^-32 I,0.*10^-32 + 0.*10^-32 I, 
   0.*10^-32 + 0.*10^-32 I, 0.*10^-32 + 0.*10^-32 I, 0.*10^-32 + 0.*10^-32 I, 
   0.*10^-32 + 0.*10^-32 I, 0.*10^-32 + 0.*10^-32 I, 
   1.5000000000000000000000000000000 + 0.*10^-32 I}
*)
```

So why I get the error only in the machine precision case? Are these errors in `Fourier[ls]` coming from *Mathematica* or related to how numbers are represented in computers?

Edit:

If we fix the precision in the calculation, we can see that the errors are smaller compared to Machine precision calculation.

```
Block[{$MaxPrecision = 8, $MinPrecision = 8}, Fourier[SetPrecision[ls, 8]]]
(* {-4.3981121*10^-35, 1.5000000, 1.8230938*10^-34, 2.1989581*10^-35, 1.8230938*10^-34, 1.8230938*10^-34, 2.1989581*10^-35, 1.8230938*10^-34, 1.5000000} *)

Block[{$MaxPrecision = 16, $MinPrecision = 16}, Fourier[SetPrecision[ls, 16]]]
(* {-4.406340574057345*10^-35, 1.500000000000000, 1.816158363592948*10^-34, 2.203268244891241*10^-35, 1.816158363592948*10^-34, 1.816158363592948*10^-34, 2.203268244891241*10^-35, 1.816158363592948*10^-34, 1.500000000000000} *)
```

Comment: In absolute terms, it isn't a large error; it represents about 1 unit in the last place, which is pretty good. It's just large in a relative sense because the values are supposed to be zero, but in this case I think there isn't any alternative to working in arbitrary precision so that you can (1) make the absolute value of 1 ULP arbitrarily small and (2) know whether the values returned have any significant digits or not.

Comment: @OleksandrR. How can we do (2)? And do you know why `Fourier[SetPrecision[ls, 16]]` seems give smaller errors?

Comment: The errors are not necessarily smaller; it is just that Mma realises that the result has no significant digits and is zero to within the available precision. The actual error or uncertainty in the results is more or less the same whether you use `MachinePrecision` or `$MachinePrecision` (though actually the total accrued error seems a bit worse for the arbitrary-precision calculation). In Mma, using arbitrary precision automatically turns on precision tracking, so you accomplish both (1) and (2) at the same time.

Comment: @OleksandrR. How can I see the error in the results are more or less the same? And how precision tracking could help to decrease the errors if the calculation are running at a fixed precision?

Comment: Compare the precision of the output with that of the input, and you'll see that about half a decimal digit is lost. Precision tracking does not decrease the error; it just causes e.g. $0.5 \pm 1.0$ to be reported as 0 rather than 0.5. This is a distinction without a difference.

Comment: Re: your edit. Note that `SetPrecision` doesn't necessarily extend/truncate the value to exactly the number of digits you specify--all it does is to produce a value with at least as many digits as necessary and whose `Precision` is as you requested. In this particular case, setting precision to 16 actually yields a value with many more places, just with most of them not significant. This is probably to prevent rounding error from becoming a problem when you ask for fixed precision.

Comment: @OleksandrR. So is it possible to simulate this procession lost, say we want to simulate a calculation with only single precision float point?

Comment: I would say probably not. At least, the fact that *Mathematica*'s numerical model differs so fundamentally from all other packages would mean that one would need to take a great deal of care to ensure that results really mean what one might think they appear to mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14436/discussion-between-xslittlegrass-and-oleksandr-r)

Answer (score 2):

When you use machine precision, it is often a good idea to apply [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html) to your result. In this case,

```
 {-6.4763*10^-17 + 0. I, 1.5 + 5.55112*10^-17 I, 1.60247*10^-17 + 2.77556*10^-17 I, 
  3.23815*10^-17 - 8.01234*10^-18 I, -1.60247*10^-17 - 2.77556*10^-17 I, 
  -1.60247*10^-17 + 2.77556*10^-17 I, 3.23815*10^-17 + 8.01234*10^-18 I, 
  1.60247*10^-17 - 2.77556*10^-17 I, 1.5 - 5.55112*10^-17 I} // Chop
```

gives

> ```
> {0, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5}
> ```

which is probably what you expected.

Comment: Yes I think this works for most of case, but I'm dealing with a problem (called high harmonic generation) which cares a lot on the small numbers. Sorry for the confusing part.

Comment: @xslittlegrass. Then you probably can't use machine arithmetic.

Comment: So are you saying that the errors are from the they way that the numbers are presented in computers, and not from Mathematica?

Comment: @xslittlegrass. Yes